# Проблема дублирования активити при старте из панели уведомлений

Tags: android, java, service, activity

Всем привет.
Есть активити, которая старнует некий сервис, в котором в свою очередь в панель уведомлений пихается уведомление с пиктограммой, при клике на которое стартует родительское активити.
Ну, т.е. сервис варится сам по себе, что-то там делает, а в активити можно сконфигурировать, что он именно делает.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, если родительское активити было на экране, а потом нажатием на кнопочку "Home", убираю его в бэкграунд, а далее запускаю кликом на уведомление, то получается дублирование активити. Т.е. перед глазами появляется активити, в нем можно видеть настройки сервиса, редактировать из и т.д., но если потом "убить" активити (в активити есть кнопка "Finish", которая его убивает, а так же и убивает сервис и снимает уведомление из панели), то активити закрывается, сервис завершает работу, но тут же вылезает на экране копия этого активити.
Т.е. получается что уйдя в фон, активити висит в памяти. Потом из менеджера уведомлений я его из фона как бы должен вытащить и всё. Но реально оно не подгружается из фона, а создается новое активити и втыкается на экран, а под ним где-то вылезает то активити которое было в фоне.
Что за чехарда, как можно побороть?

P.S. Аналогичная байда была и по сворачиванию нажатием на кнопку Back. Но тут решилось просто - отлавливаю событие нажатия на эту кнопку и убиваю активити. И тогда при вызове из менеджера уведомлений оно честно и в единственном экземпляре создается заново. Но вот как быть в выше описанном случае???

Comment: К интенту, который будет запускаться из уведомления, добавьте флаг:

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

[`Android: Clear the back stack`][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack

Comment: К сожалению не помогает. Результат тот же.
Не подходит в моем случае и опция 
android:noHistory="true"
Т.к. я использую вызов из главной активити дочерних через startActivityForResult. И при отключенной истории, после вызова дочерней, главная активити "благополучно" уходит в небытие :(

Надо как-то иначе... А вот как??..

Comment: PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, а stackBuilder - это что за объект?

Сейчас уведомление создаю так:

NotificationManager notfMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "", 0);
notification.flags |=  Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"MyApp","", contentIntent);
ntfMgr.notify(NTF_ID, notification);

может что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: извиняюсь, я таки по ходу ещё не имею достаточно прав на отметки какие-либо. пытаюсь нажать на иконку с пальцем вверх - пишет, что низзя...
или как-то по-иному отмечают ответы как правильные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запускать Activity, используя TaskStackBuilder из android.support.v4(если до ICS).

Делается примерно так.

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.LAUNCH_HANDLED,false);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    //set back stack
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_image)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.flags |= (closable ? Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL : Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(sNotificationID, n);
```

Создаем с помощью TaskStackBuilder PendingIntent, засовываем его в NotificationCompat.Builder и затем генерируем Notification.

stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class); делает Activity родительской.

Answer (score 1):

android:launchMode="singleTop"

Answer (score 0):

Ага, вроде понял.
Сделал через `TaskStackBuilder` c использованием `intent.addFlags`

```
(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

и

```
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Вроде бы помогло. Буду проверять.